# best coding style for iterators

Tags: c++, coding-style

A fellow overflower said that this made his eyes bleed:

```
for (std::vector<Agent*>::const_iterator iter = agents.begin(); iter != agents.end(); ++iter)
{
    delete *iter;
}
```

What's a neater way of writing it? I suppose I could typedef the iterator type, but in some classes that would mean a huge block of typedef's at the top which I think looks horrible.

Comment: this question is off-topic here: post it on codereview

Comment: You could at least break up the 3 components of the for onto separate lines

Comment: Use a vector of smart pointers.

Comment: Isn't using plain pointers and needing this code in the first place the biggest issue here?

Answer (score 2):

I would typedef `std::vector<Agent*>`.

Comment: that's actually a really good point, saves me for having to typedef ::size_type and ::iterator and:: const_iterator all seperately

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 you can do [range based for](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html) loops

```
map<string, string> address_book;
for ( auto address_entry : address_book )
{
  cout  << address_entry.first << " < " << address_entry.second << ">" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <algorithm>

void delete_(Agent* agent) {
    delete agent;
}
...

std::for_each(agents.begin(), agents.end(), delete_);
```

Answer (score 2):

You've gotten a number of answers already, but I will posit that the problem is much...deeper than they imply. Most of them are looking primarily (or exclusively) at the syntax you're using, which I think is generally the least of the problems here. They're treating the symptom, not the disease.

For the `for` loop you've posted to make sense, you have a collection of pointers to objects that are allocated with `new`. Moreover, the fact that you're deleting all the objects in the container implies that you're basically associating ownership of the objects with that container.

As I said above, the `for` loop is a symptom. The disease is the design. When you fix the design, you won't have to worry about the syntax of the `for` loop, because you won't need that loop at all any more.

That leaves a serious question: why are you storing pointers to objects in the first place? Perhaps the objects are expensive to copy, and you're worried that when the vector expands its allocation, copying the objects will be too slow. Chances are that in this case, you're just mistaken. Its well known that `vector` expands its allocation exponentially so that insertion has amortized constant complexity. What isn't quite so well known or obvious is that the same exponential growth also means that the average number of copies of existing objects asymptotically approaches a constant. In a typical implementation, the average number of copies will be somewhere between 2 and 3. As such, chances are pretty good that you can just create a vector of objects and your efficiency will remain perfectly adequate. In this case, your loop turns into (at most) `agents.clear()` (and chances are pretty good even that won't really be needed).

If you are in one of the relatively rare situations where that copying really is a problem, then you might want (for example) define `agents` as a `vector<shared_ptr<agent> >` instead of using raw pointers. Here again, deleting the pointee objects is no longer needed because `shared_ptr` will handle that automatically when the objects' reference counts reach 0.

For C++11, you can (often) accomplish much the same thing by supporting move semantics instead of copying. Assuming you can count on support in all your compilers, this may improve simplicity and efficiency even further.

That's probably not an exhaustive list of possibilities, and some of the others might lead to slightly different cures. The point remains the same though: figure out what's really wrong, and fix that.

I'll repeat, however: right now, you're looking at a symptom. You need to fix the disease, which will make the symptom disappear.

Edit: As usual, somebody appears to have misunderstood (or failed to understand) how vectors work. For the sake of argument, I'll use his example of 64K elements. To keep the math as simple as possible, I'll further assume that the vector is completely full, and that this implementation precisely doubles the size of the vector when resizing is needed.

In this case, 32K of the elements have never been copied. Another 16K have been copied once. Another 8K have been copied twice. Another 4K have been copied three times, 2K four times, 1K five times, 512 six times, 256 seven, 128 eight, 64 nine, 32 ten, 16 eleven, 8 twelve, 4 thirteen, and 2 fourteen times and 1 fifteen times (though, of course, in reality a real implementation is likely to start with at least 8 or 10 elements, though it makes little difference). Dividing that sum by 64K gives us the average number of times elements have been copied:

So, what we get is:

```
  32K* 0
 +16K* 1
 + 8k* 2
 + 4K* 3
 + 2K* 4
 + 1K* 5
 +512* 6
 +256* 7
 +128* 8
 + 64* 9
 + 32* 10
 + 16* 11
 +  8* 12
 +  4* 13
 +  2* 14
 +  1* 15
 =  65519
```

Dividing that by 65536 gives the average number of times an element in the vector has been copied -- 0.999741. If we add just one more element, we copy each of those elements one more time, and have only one element that's been copied 0 times. That gives us an average of 1.99971.

I doubt it takes a whole lot of imagination to figure out the upper and lower bounds from those: 1 and 2 respectively.

In reality, few implementations work quite that way. Most set a larger minimum size (often something like 10 or 20 elements), and most use a smaller growth factor. The larger minimum size reduces the actual number of copies for many practical sizes. The smaller growth factor increases the upper bound -- but (importantly) the upper bound is still always a constant.

Comment: I disagree in principle with just about everything you wrote in this post. It's subjective, so I won't downvote it. A factual mistake: in a typical implementation, the vector size is usually *at most* doubled, so number of copies is *at least* O(log n). 64k elements ~= 16 copies.

Comment: @zvrba: you are, of course, welcome to your own opinion -- even though it's wrong! :-) As far as the bound on the number of copies, however, you seem to have missed the fact that I was talking about the average -- or at least what that implied. See the edited answer for further explanation.

Comment: +1 I'd suggest `boost::ptr_vector`, or `boost::poly_collection::base_container` (a la http://bannalia.blogspot.nl/2014/05/fast-polymorphic-collections.html). That is, without more information about the specific use case

Answer (score 1):

Is Boost something you can consider?
In such typical "for each" loop, you may use Boost's foreach:

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

BOOST_FOREACH(Agent* a, agents) {
    delete a;
}
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/foreach.html

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<Agent*>::const_iterator iter = agents.begin(); 


 while( iter != agents.end() )
 {
     delete * iter;
     iter++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Boost Foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/foreach.html), with a #define to make it even prettier.

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#define foreach BOOST_FOREACH

...

foreach(Agent* p, agents)
{
  delete p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, my eyes bleed because this line exceeds 80 columns :)

Try this:

```
std::vector<Agent*>::const_iterator iter;
for (iter = agents.begin(); iter != agents.end(); ++iter)
{
    delete *iter;
}
```

Comment: This leaves `iter` dangling around in the enclosing scope whereas defining it in the `for` loop does not.

Answer (score 0):

C++2011 is your friend:

```
std::for_each(agents.begin(), agents.end(),
                      [](Agent* agent){ delete agent; });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect he/she was complaining about explicitly writing out the for loop for an STL range.  There are alternatives, like `std::for_each` from `<algorithms>`.  With newer compilers, you can also use `auto` and lambda expressions to write this more concisely.